# How to control the position of the picture in moderncv?

Tags: moderncv

[image]

I would like to push the information text to a below part of the picture in the classic theme from the class moderncv. Is that possible? And how?

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans,english]{moderncv}        % possible options include font size ('10pt', '11pt' and '12pt'), paper size ('a4paper', 'letterpaper', 'a5paper', 'legalpaper', 'executivepaper' and 'landscape') and font family ('sans' and 'roman')
\moderncvstyle{classic}                             % style options are 'casual' (default), 'classic', 'oldstyle' and 'banking'
\moderncvcolor{blue}                               % color options 'blue' (default), 'orange', 'green', 'red', 'purple', 'grey' and 'black'
%\nopagenumbers{}                                  % uncomment to suppress automatic page numbering for CVs longer than one page
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                       % if you are not using xelatex ou lualatex, replace by the encoding you are using
\usepackage[scale=0.75,a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{babel}
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%            personal data
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\firstname{first name}
\familyname{family name}
\title{Resumé title}                               % optional, remove/comment the line if not wanted
\address{street and number}{postcode city}{country}         % optional, remove/comment the line if not wanted; the "country" arguments can be omitted or provided empty
\mobile{mobile number}                          % optional, remove/comment the line if not wanted
\phone{phone number}                           % optional, remove/comment the line if not wanted
\fax{fax number}                             % optional, remove/comment the line if not wanted
\email{email}                               % optional, remove/comment the line if not wanted
\homepage{home page}                         % optional, remove/comment the line if not wanted
\extrainfo{additional information}                 % optional, remove/comment the line if not wanted
% \photo[64pt][0.4pt]{picture}                       % optional, uncomment the line if wanted; '64pt' is the height the picture must be resized to, 0.4pt is the thickness of the frame around it (put it to 0pt for no frame) and 'picture' is the name of the picture file
\quote{some quote}                                 % optional, remove/comment the line if not wanted
%
\begin{document}
%-----       resume       ---------------------------------------------------------
\makecvtitle
\section{Education}
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{Grade}{Description}  % arguments 3 to 6 can be left empty
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{Grade}{Description}
\section{Master thesis}
\cvitem{title}{Title}
\cvitem{supervisors}{Supervisors}
\cvitem{description}{Short thesis abstract}
\section{Experience}
\subsection{Vocational}
\cventry{year--year}{Job title}{Employer}{City}{}{General description no longer than 1--2 lines}
\cventry{year--year}{Job title}{Employer}{City}{}{General description no longer than 1--2 lines}
\subsection{Miscellaneous}
\cventry{year--year}{Job title}{Employer}{City}{}{General description no longer than 1--2 lines}
\section{Languages}
\cvitemwithcomment{Language 1}{Skill level}{Comment}
\cvitemwithcomment{Language 2}{Skill level}{Comment}
\cvitemwithcomment{Language 3}{Skill level}{Comment}
\section{Computer skills}
\cvdoubleitem{Category 1}{Comment}{Category 4}{Comment}
\cvdoubleitem{Category 2}{Comment}{Category 5}{Comment}
\cvdoubleitem{Category 3}{Comment}{Category 6}{Comment}
\section{Interests}
\cvitem{Hobby 1}{Description}
\cvitem{Hobby 2}{Description}
\cvitem{Hobby 3}{Description}
\section{Extra 1}
\cvlistitem{Item 1}
\cvlistitem{Item 2}
\cvlistitem{Item 3}
\section{Extra 2}
\cvlistdoubleitem{Item 1}{Item 4}
\cvlistdoubleitem{Item 2}{Item 5}
\cvlistdoubleitem{Item 3}{Item 6}
\section{References}
\begin{cvcolumns}
  \cvcolumn{Category 1}{Comment}
  \cvcolumn{Category 2}{Comment}
  \cvcolumn{Category 3}{Comment}
\end{cvcolumns}
\clearpage
%-----       letter       ---------------------------------------------------------
% recipient data
\recipient{Company Recruitment team}{Company's name\\Street address\\Zip Code City}
\date{Date}
\opening{Dear Sir or Madam,}
\closing{Yours faithfully,}
\enclosure{enclosures}          % use an optional argument to use a string other than "Enclosure", or redefine \enclname
\makelettertitle
\makeletterclosing
\end{document}
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: Hello and welcome to TeX.SE. Please add also `...\end{document}`. So everyone can compile it easily. (example image:`example-image`)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please google this site for similar questions. I'm quite sure, that your question is duplicate to some exited ...

Comment: Thank you. I was not able to find an answer, sorry if it is duplicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you have to rewrite the table used to create the title of the resume. To be able to do that I copied some lines of the code from class `moderncv` into the resume (code between commands `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`).

Please see that the following code is only working with class version 2.0.0.  If the class version number changes it is possible one have to rewrite the code ...

Please see the following MWE (important parts of the code are marked with `<=======`):

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans,english]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{classic}
\moderncvcolor{blue}
%\nopagenumbers{}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[scale=0.75,a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{babel}

\makeatletter  % <======================================================
\renewcommand*{\makecvhead}{%
  % recompute lengths (in case we are switching from letter to resume, or vice versa)
  \recomputecvlengths%
  % optional detailed information (pre-rendering)
  \@initializebox{\makecvheaddetailsbox}%
  \if@details%
    \def\phonesdetails{}%
    \collectionloop{phones}{% the key holds the phone type (=symbol command prefix), the item holds the number
      \protected@edef\phonesdetails{\phonesdetails\protect\makenewline\csname\collectionloopkey phonesymbol\endcsname\collectionloopitem}}%
    \def\socialsdetails{}%
    \collectionloop{socials}{% the key holds the social type (=symbol command prefix), the item holds the link
      \protected@edef\socialsdetails{\socialsdetails\protect\makenewline\csname\collectionloopkey socialsymbol\endcsname\collectionloopitem}}%
    \savebox{\makecvheaddetailsbox}{%
      \addressfont\color{color2}%
      \if@left\begin{tabular}[b]{@{}r@{}}\fi%
      \if@right\begin{tabular}[b]{@{}l@{}}\fi%
        \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@photo}}{}{\makenewline % <===========
           \setlength{\fboxrule}{\@photoframewidth}%        <===========
          \ifdim\@photoframewidth=0pt%                      <===========
            \setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}\fi%                   <===========
          \framebox{\includegraphics[width=\@photowidth]{\@photo}}% <===
        }%                                                  <===========
        \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@addressstreet}}{}{\makenewline\addresssymbol\@addressstreet%
          \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscity}{}}{}{\makenewline\@addresscity}% if \addresstreet is defined, \addresscity and addresscountry will always be defined but could be empty
          \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscountry}{}}{}{\makenewline\@addresscountry}}%
        \phonesdetails% needs to be pre-rendered as loops and tabulars seem to conflict
        \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@email}}{}{\makenewline\emailsymbol\emaillink{\@email}}%
        \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@homepage}}{}{\makenewline\homepagesymbol\httplink{\@homepage}}%
        \socialsdetails% needs to be pre-rendered as loops and tabulars seem to conflict
        \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@extrainfo}}{}{\makenewline\@extrainfo}%
      \end{tabular}
    }\fi%
  % optional photo (pre-rendering)
  \@initializebox{\makecvheadpicturebox}%
  \savebox{\makecvheadpicturebox}{%
    \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@photo}}%
      {}%
      {%
        %\if@left%                                        <=============
          %\hspace*{\separatorcolumnwidth}\fi%
        %\color{color1}%
        %\setlength{\fboxrule}{\@photoframewidth}%
        %\ifdim\@photoframewidth=0pt%
          %\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}\fi%
        %\framebox{\includegraphics[width=\@photowidth]{\@photo}}%
      }%
        %\if@right%
          %\hspace*{\separatorcolumnwidth}\fi %           <=============
  }%
  % name and title (pre-rendering)
  \@initializelength{\makecvheaddetailswidth}\settowidth{\makecvheaddetailswidth}{\usebox{\makecvheaddetailsbox}}%
  \@initializelength{\makecvheadpicturewidth}\settowidth{\makecvheadpicturewidth}{\usebox{\makecvheadpicturebox}}%
  \ifthenelse{\lengthtest{\makecvheadnamewidth=0pt}}% check for dummy value (equivalent to \ifdim\makecvheadnamewidth=0pt)
    {\setlength{\makecvheadnamewidth}{\textwidth-\makecvheaddetailswidth-\makecvheadpicturewidth}}%
    {}%
  \@initializebox{\makecvheadnamebox}%
  \savebox{\makecvheadnamebox}{%
    \begin{minipage}[b]{\makecvheadnamewidth}%
      \if@left\raggedright\fi%
      \if@right\raggedleft\fi%
      \namestyle{\@firstname\ \@lastname}%
      \ifthenelse{\equal{\@title}{}}{}{\\[1.25em]\titlestyle{\@title}}%
    \end{minipage}}%
  % rendering
  \if@left%
    \usebox{\makecvheadnamebox}%
    \hfill%
    \llap{\usebox{\makecvheaddetailsbox}}% \llap is used to suppress the width of the box, allowing overlap if the value of makecvheadnamewidth is forced
    \usebox{\makecvheadpicturebox}\fi%
  \if@right%
    \usebox{\makecvheadpicturebox}%
    \rlap{\usebox{\makecvheaddetailsbox}}% \llap is used to suppress the width of the box, allowing overlap if the value of makecvheadnamewidth is forced
    \hfill%
    \usebox{\makecvheadnamebox}\fi%
  \\[2.5em]%
  % optional quote
  \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@quote}}%
    {}%
    {{\centering\begin{minipage}{\quotewidth}\centering\quotestyle{\@quote}\end{minipage}\\[2.5em]}}%
  \par}% to avoid weird spacing bug at the first section if no blank line is left after \makecvhead

\makeatother      % <===================================================


%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%            personal data
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\firstname{first name}
\familyname{family name}
\title{Resumé title}                               % optional, remove/comment the line if not wanted
\address{street and number}{postcode city}{country}         % optional, remove/comment the line if not wanted; the "country" arguments can be omitted or provided empty
\mobile{mobile number}                          % optional, remove/comment the line if not wanted
\phone{phone number}                           % optional, remove/comment the line if not wanted
\fax{fax number}                             % optional, remove/comment the line if not wanted
\email{email}                               % optional, remove/comment the line if not wanted
\homepage{home page}                         % optional, remove/comment the line if not wanted
\extrainfo{additional information}                 % optional, remove/comment the line if not wanted
 \photo[64pt][0.4pt]{example-image-a}       % optional, uncomment the line if wanted; '64pt' is the height the picture must be resized to, 0.4pt is the thickness of the frame around it (put it to 0pt for no frame) and 'picture' is the name of the picture file
\quote{some quote}                                 % optional, remove/comment the line if not wanted
%
\begin{document}
%-----       resume       ---------------------------------------------------------
\makecvtitle
\section{Education}
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{Grade}{Description}  % arguments 3 to 6 can be left empty
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{Grade}{Description}
\section{Master thesis}
\cvitem{title}{Title}
\cvitem{supervisors}{Supervisors}
\cvitem{description}{Short thesis abstract}
\section{Experience}
\subsection{Vocational}
\cventry{year--year}{Job title}{Employer}{City}{}{General description no longer than 1--2 lines}
\cventry{year--year}{Job title}{Employer}{City}{}{General description no longer than 1--2 lines}
\subsection{Miscellaneous}
\cventry{year--year}{Job title}{Employer}{City}{}{General description no longer than 1--2 lines}
\section{Languages}
\cvitemwithcomment{Language 1}{Skill level}{Comment}
\cvitemwithcomment{Language 2}{Skill level}{Comment}
\cvitemwithcomment{Language 3}{Skill level}{Comment}
\section{Computer skills}
\cvdoubleitem{Category 1}{Comment}{Category 4}{Comment}
\cvdoubleitem{Category 2}{Comment}{Category 5}{Comment}
\cvdoubleitem{Category 3}{Comment}{Category 6}{Comment}
\section{Interests}
\cvitem{Hobby 1}{Description}
\cvitem{Hobby 2}{Description}
\cvitem{Hobby 3}{Description}
\section{Extra 1}
\cvlistitem{Item 1}
\cvlistitem{Item 2}
\cvlistitem{Item 3}
\section{Extra 2}
\cvlistdoubleitem{Item 1}{Item 4}
\cvlistdoubleitem{Item 2}{Item 5}
\cvlistdoubleitem{Item 3}{Item 6}
\section{References}
\begin{cvcolumns}
  \cvcolumn{Category 1}{Comment}
  \cvcolumn{Category 2}{Comment}
  \cvcolumn{Category 3}{Comment}
\end{cvcolumns}
\clearpage
%-----       letter       ---------------------------------------------------------
% recipient data
\recipient{Company Recruitment team}{Company's name\\Street address\\Zip Code City}
\date{Date}
\opening{Dear Sir or Madam,}
\closing{Yours faithfully,}
\enclosure{enclosures}          % use an optional argument to use a string other than "Enclosure", or redefine \enclname
\makelettertitle
\makeletterclosing
\end{document}
```

with the resulting pdf:

[image: resulting title page]